# "single-row subquery returns more than one row" three table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm having problems when entering payroll data into a column.

Table AA

```
ID_USER      PERIOD          SALARY          

1001        1-MAY-2012         ?
1002        1-MAY-2012         ?
1001        1-JUN-2012         ?
1002        1-JUN-2012         ?
```

Table BB

```
  ID_USER      Name          ID_SALARY           

1001        Rayker          1
1002        Jones           2
1003        Wiliam          2
```

Table CC

```
    ID_SALARY    SALARY             

  1          $50          
  2          $60
```

Here's my script:

```
UPDATE "AA" A 
SET A.SALARY = (select C.SALARY from "BB" B,"CC" C where B.ID_SALARY=C.ID_SALARY)
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT B.ID_USER FROM "AA" A, "BB" B  WHERE A.ID_USER = B.ID_USER )
ORDER BY A.ID_USER
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this must be enough

```
UPDATE "AA" A 
SET A.SALARY = (select C.SALARY from "BB" B,"CC" C where B.ID_SALARY=C.ID_SALARY AND B.ID_USER = A.ID_USER)
```